# qt creator can not load icon

Tags: c++, image, qt

I am a beginer of QT, I tried to add an action to a toolbar and I wrote as follows:

```
toolbar->addAction(QIcon("/icons/new.png"), "New File");
```

However, the image can not be loaded. Is that related to my debug path? I can see the button, but no images.
those codes are in test.cpp and my icons folder is in the same path with test.cpp

Comment: what is your OS? did you specify your icon in qt resource file or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paths are interesting.

If you are on linux, you just specified that the root of the drive has a folder called `icons`, and inside it it has a file called `new.png`.

If you were using that kind of a path on a website, it would chop off everything to the left besides the domain and subdomain names.

`example.com/path/to/some/folder/index.html`, processes link to `/icons/new.png`, and you end up at: `example.com/icons/new.png`.

The best way to handle paths correctly is to use common notations for relative paths (in most cases... in some cases, absolute paths make sense).

`./` means the folder that I am currently in aka the working directory.

`../` means the folder above me.

A leading `/` means the highest folder possible or the root folder, on Unix systems.  It is also akin to giving an absolute path for a file.

No leading `.` or `..` or `/` means the same as `./`, or from the working directory.

And there are even more rules about this.  See the wiki entry:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

In Qt there is also the resource system, that embeds files into the exe itself and can give you a harder-to-change image or graphic on your program.

The notation to access this is:

`:/` means the root of the qresource system.

And if you do decide there is a reason to use a backslash, be sure to escape it.  Normally Qt will take any input with backslashes and convert it for you on the fly to forward slashes.

So to double check that the file is there, use `QFile file("icons/new.png");` followed by `if(!file.exists()){ qDebug() << "File is not found!" << file.fileName(); }`

Sometimes I find it helpful to see where my program is when this is happening.  Either using `system("dir");` or `qDebug() << QDir::currentPath();`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qdir.html#currentPath

You can also see what your initial working directory is by looking at your project properties for the project in Qt Creator under:

```
Projects (tab) > Run (tab) > Run > Working directory:
```

Usually it is the root of where your source code is and where your `.pro` file is located.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Qt resources then you need a colon:

```
toolbar->addAction(QIcon(":/icons/new.png"), "New File");`
```

if you don't use resources then yuo should use relative path. Remember that Qt Creator uses by default "build in different place" so you must make sure that icon is deployed in respective directory.